# Run foreground ksh script in background

Tags: ksh

How do I run a foreground ksh script in the background? I have a script I do not have the ability to edit, which needs to be ran in the background.

My call to it is `sh biw96inst.sh $1 $2 $3 $4 $5, etc` I have tried `nohup`, `&` at the end, `-f` before the script name, and none are working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Type ctrl+z and then bg. ctrl+z will suspend it and bg will put the process into the background. fg will put it into the foreground, ie. resume.

Comment: Does the cntl-Z and bg let it run in the background? or do I have to type fg to start again?

Comment: Yes, it will suspend the running process and bg will put it into the background. You don't need to type fg.